# iOS, Swift, UIAlertController, UIAlertAction - How to turn dismiss animation off when button is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uialertcontroller

When a button is pressed on this UIAlertController it automatically dismisses with animation. Can I turn animation off?

I have tried presenting as animated : false but still dismisses with animation.

```
      func showOKMessage(title: String, message : String) {
        self.alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        self.alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(self.alertController, animated: true)
  }
```

Comment: can you add code please

Comment: code please sims like an easy fix

Comment: In simliar situations I have found disabling the button is a good workaround, I'm not sure this would help in your case without more information though.

Comment: @code_bash - Added code

Comment: @Ram - Added code

Comment: @thefredelement - thanks for the suggestion however I need use of the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First what I tried is, to create a reference of an `UIAlertController` to handle to set the animation in `dismiss(animated:completion:)` to `false` in the handler (The code which will be executed after you press the OK button) of the `UIAlertAction`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var alert: UIAlertController!

  @IBAction func alertViewButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Hello", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
      // this code executes after you hit the OK button
      self.alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
  }
}
```

**Unfortunately the animation is still there:**

[image]

The only way what worked for me is just to `override` the `dismiss(animated:completion:)` method and set the animated flag in the call of `super` to `false`. You also don't need to add code to the handler and there is no reason to create a reference for that solution. (Note: Now every presented view controller gets dismissed without animation in that view controller):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func alertViewButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Hello", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
  }

  override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    // view controller which was presented modally by the view controller gets dismissed now without animation
    super.dismiss(animated: false, completion: completion)
  }
}
```

**Now the alert view gets dismissed without animation:**

[image]

Comment: Can anyone provide a workaround per alert view and not a for all fix?